# python: assigning parts of a string to variables

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I need some help learning to think like a programmer.

I'm using beautifulsoup4 to grab content. There are three strings I want inside of a p tag. The first two are strings for child a tags. The third is a string of the p tab. It looks like this:

```
<p>
<a href="some stuff">First String</a>
<br/>
<a href="some stuff">Second String</a>
<br/>
Third String
<br/>
unimportant fourth string
<br/>
</p>
```

I'd like to assign each string to its own variable, but I can't figure out how to separate them. Seems I ought to be able to split into lines then assign each line. My code currently looks like this:

```
events=body.find_all('p') #find all the p tags
for strings in events[3]: #get the first of the p tags i'm interested in
    if strings.string:
        all= str(strings.string).splitlines() #puts each string on its own line
        for line in all: #shouldn't I be able to get each line by its index?
            print line
```

Whatever I try, I get all three lines. I've spent hours trying different things, and I'm hoping that someone here can tell me the right way to think about it.

Thanks

Comment: HTML is not newline delimited so you can't rely on line breaks to parse it. You should get the text node for each element.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable = {} # a dictionary
variable_names = ['line-1', 'line-2', 'line-3', 'line-4']

events=body.find_all('p')
for strings in events[3]:
    if strings.string:
        all= str(strings.string).splitlines()
        for i,line in enumerate(all):
            variable[variable_names[i]] = line

        # test
        print variable['line-1']
```